# Configuring PNG on ImageMagick on a Linux Server

Tags: linux, delegates, imagemagick, png, libpng

I have been trying to run the following script on ImageMagick on a Linux server

```
convert resized.png -gravity Center -crop 1024X768+0+0 +repage flower.png
```

but have been hitting the following error:

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `flower.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3212.
```

It looks like there is no delegate for PNG.

When I run:

```
identify -version
```

I get this result that shows that the PNG delegate is not installed:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-4 Q16 x86_64 2015-01-25       http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jpeg lcms tiff x zlib
```

As far as I can tell I have 'libpng' installed on my server.

How do I configure the PNG delegate for ImageMagick on my Linux server?

I have 'yum' installed but not 'apt-get'.

Answer (score 12):

I did a lot more searching and found this answer.

It looks like ImageMagick did not know what library to look for.

I did a

```
locate libpng
```

and found that it was located in

```
/usr/lib64/
```

I was then able to run the commands on this page (from within the ImageMagick directory):

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=12366

```
./configure --enable-shared
make libdir=/usr/lib64
make libdir=/usr/lib64 install
./configure --enable-shared=yes --x-libraries=/usr/lib64 --without-perl
make
make install
```

Then running

```
identify -version
```

showed the following results:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-4 Q16 x86_64 2015-01-30
 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jpeg lcms png tiff x zlib
```

which shows that PNG is now installed as a delegate.

Comment: I cannot get this working :( http://askubuntu.com/questions/745660/imagemagick-png-delegate-install-problems

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. The only problem was I needed to install also the **libpng-devel** package. Then just running plain `./configure` with no extra parameters (followed by `make` etc.) was just enough.