# How to add delegates to ImageMagick in Gentoo

Tags: linux, imagemagick, gentoo

How can one add more delegates to ImageMagick?  I'm on gentoo (so, `emerge`), and while I see a plethora of links to different issues, I've not found any general how-to's:

- [This](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=12366) points to the source of the delegate libraries [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/)
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319327/1789543) points to the need to install underlying image libraries (e.g. libpng), and seems to generally be a repository for everyone's ImageMagick "no decode delegate" questions.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237800/configuring-png-on-imagemagick-on-a-linux-server) sort of points back to a second person's issue in the first bullet, though it makes use of a `./configure` command that I don't see in my ImageMagick directory
- And finally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33264020/1789543) might be the answer I need, though the syntax is garbled such that I cannot tell what the intended command is.

In particular, none of these explain what exactly one must do with the delegate libraries [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/), if they do indeed need to be installed manually.  Anyway, my delegates are currently listed (via `convert -list configure|grep -i delegate`) as bzlib, mpeg, and zlib.  I've installed media-libs/libpng, media-libs/tiff, and media-libs/libjpeg-turbo.  I didn't grab media-libs/jasper, as it's not clear whether it is necessary.  Removing and then installing ImageMagick anew after this (`sudo emerge -cav media-gfx/imagemagick` then `sudo emerge -v media-gfx/imagemagick`) didn't change any of my delegates.

Comment: Sorry, I  know little about Gentoo, but doing a Google search, I found this, which may be of use.  https://gentoobrowse.randomdan.homeip.net/packages/media-gfx/imagemagick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

A number of these can be handled by setting the USE flags on the imagemagick package. Some use flags can be found by looking at the package's entry on [packages.gentoo.org](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/media-gfx/imagemagick). For a definitive list, check the ebuild on your machine or use tools such as [`equery`](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Equery).

## Details

Portage, gentoo's package manager, is actually just a list of steps needed to build a package from source. USE flags allow you to customize that process. In this case, it changes which packages are built as dependencies.

## Steps

One way to set the USE flags is to create a file in `/etc/portage/package.use` and write the package name on it's own line followed by all the use flag you would like to set. (eg. `=media-gfx/imagemagick-7.0.8.8 png` would set the `png` flag for version 7.0.8.8.

Once the USE flags are set, re-emerge the package to build with the new settings (eg. `emerge --ask --verbose =media-gfx/imagemagick-7.0.8.8`)

For more details on USE flags, read https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/USE_flag

Comment: I don't see the `png` USE flag on that first link, is there a more complete list somewhere else?  I see more flags listed in the link in @fmw42's comment. 
 You also didn't mention delegate libraries, does that mean I don't need to do anything with them manually?

Comment: The ultimate source of truth with regards to use flags is the ebuild file itself. They are usually found in `/usr/portage`. For a more user-friendly interface, you can install `gentoolkit` and use the `equery` command to get details about a package. (eg. `equery u media-gfx/imagemagick` will show all the use flags for the imagemagick package)

Comment: I presumed that the official gentoo package site would list all the use flags, but apparently not. You can see from the [ebuild itself](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/media-gfx/imagemagick/imagemagick-7.0.8.8.ebuild) that there is, indeed, a `png` flag

Comment: ...and, yes, the use flags take care of installing and configuring the 'delegates'

Comment: OK, this works, thanks.  Can you revise the first bit of your answer about where to find USE flags?  Then, I'll accept.

Comment: @TTT Sure, I can do that.